# %s in String.format for numbers

Tags: java, printf

Is there any reason not to use `%s` for the format specifier when formatting numbers if no extra formatting is required?

e.g.

```
int answer = 42;
String text = String.format("The answer is %s", answer);
```

rather than the more usual:

```
int answer = 42;
String text = String.format("The answer is %d", answer);
```

The reason I'm asking is that I want to make some automated changes to source code, and it would be inconvenient to have to figure out whether the type of `answer` is `int` or `String` or something else

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I would expect there to be a potential difference in terms of thousands separators and other locale-specific options. The first approach is just going to call `Integer.toString` (which is not locale-sensitive) because `Integer` doesn't implement `Formattable`. The second is going to use potentially locale-sensitive integer formatting - it *could* insert thousands separators, potentially even use a different set of digits etc.

Looking at the docs more carefully, it looks like grouping separators won't be applied without a specific formatting flag, but:

> **Number Localization Algorithm**
>
> After digits are obtained for the integer part, fractional part, and exponent (as appropriate for the data type), the following transformation is applied:
>
> - Each digit character d in the string is replaced by a locale-specific digit computed relative to the current locale's zero digit z; that is d -  '0'  + z.

Sample where it makes a difference:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Locale.setDefault(new Locale("hi", "IN"));
    System.out.printf("String: %s; Number: %d\n", 1234, 1234);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try `String.format(new Locale("hi", "IN"), "%d", 1234)`, it produces `१२३४`. `new Locale("th", "TH", "TH"), "%d", 1234)` produces `๑๒๓๔`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer: Yes, I was just coming up with an example myself. Wish I'd refreshed the page earlier :)

Comment: Hmm... So changing `"The answer is " + answer` to `String.format("The answer is %d", answer)` is a change of behaviour, but changing it to `String.format("The answer is %s", answer)` isn't?

Comment: @SimonNickerson: Yes, that's right. Of course, whether it will *actually* change the behaviour depends on your default locale.

Comment: +1: Interesting answer.  I've actually been caught countless times by applying %d to a non-"numeric" object (including BigDecimal) ... usually in a log statement where I'm trying to log an exception.  Wish there was a "best efforts" String.format that could get round this.